# Joomla custom fields management

Tags: custom-field, form-fields-types, fields

I'm new to Joomla'scustom fields and also don't have a deep knowledge of Joomla.

I need to create a custom field name "Speakers" to associate to a event. It's a multiselect field so that when inserting an article there should be the possibility to add multiple speakers.

Additionally, I need the possibility to manage the speakers, so that if one new speaker appears it could be added.

I assume that this is very easy to do, but as I said I don't know much of custom fields.

Comment: Look for: regularlabs article field

Comment: thanks.
Saw it and I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the built-in custom field types.

1. Go to Content > Fields
2. Create a field with the name "Speakers" of type "Checkboxes".
3. Create the values (at the bottom of the page).
4. Go to an article and under the "Fields" tab, check/select the speakers you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the [Tag](https://docs.joomla.org/Tag_form_field_type) field provided in native joomla and build your own field on top of it.

A sample tutorial on how to build a custom field is provided here https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type .

Assuming that you are building a custom component for your events management, also take time to go through the code in these files:

- /libraries/cms/html/tag.php
- /layouts/joomla/html/tag.php
- administrator/components/com_tags/*

You will get ample knowledge on how to go about your problem.

A sample of the tags field in usage is found when editing an article. Go to content manager -> Articles -> New Article and look for the tags field in the right.

If that's too much work and you don't want your users to add new speakers to your database, then you can simply provide a list of predefined speakers and let users select from that through a normal select field.

Comment: Thank you very much.
There's only one problem: I'm not a programmer, I'm more a webdesigner with very few knowledges of programming.
I'll try to see what I can do.
Thank you.